# How can a Thread communicate with another Thread without getting the "current Thread is not owner" failure?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, synchronized

so I'm trying to rebuild the consumer/producer pattern in Java. I create 20 ListInserter(Producer) and 20 ListNibbler(Consumer), which share one List. They are created like first Inserter, then nibbler, then inserter etc. Every Instance got a Constructer with the parameters(list, Runnable thread), so if an Instance is created, it gets the list and the last created Thread to communicate with.

That mean Nibbler gets (list, (last created) inserter)
and Inserter gets (list, (last created) nibbler).

I want the Nibbler, to wait at the beginning of his run method, so that the next inserter, that got the Nibbler as a parameter can notify him, when he added something to the list. Tmy problem is, it throws an Exception and I just dont get why, or how I can fix it. I will show you the code:

```
public class ListNibbler implements Runnable {

volatile List<Integer> list;
Runnable thread;

public ListNibbler(List<Integer> list, Runnable thread) {
    this.list = list;
    this.thread = thread;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    
    // This is the critical code!
    try {
        this.getClass().wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    ListEL<Integer> element = null;
    
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * list.getSize());
    
    try {
        while(list.getHead() == null) {
        Thread.sleep(5);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    element = list.remove(random);

    System.out.println(this + " eating " + element.val);
}
```

}

public class ListInserter implements Runnable{

```
volatile List<Integer> list;
Runnable thread;

public ListInserter(List<Integer> list, Runnable thread) {
    this.list = list;
    this.thread = thread;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println(this + " inserted " + random);
        list.addElement(random);

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // nichts
    }
    
    // This is the critical code
    thread.notify();
}
```

}

public class List{

```
// Erstes Element der verketteten Liste
private volatile ListEL<T> head;

// Die verkettete Liste, in der die ListEL-Objekte "gespeichert" werden
static volatile List<Integer> list = new List<>();

// Getter des Ersten Elements der Liste
public ListEL<T> getHead() {
    return head;
}

// Setter des ersten Elements der Liste
public void setHead(ListEL<T> head) {
    this.head = head;
}

// Added ein neues Element zur Liste
public void addElement(T value) {
    
    // eine Kopie des ersten Elements wird erstellt
    ListEL<T> element = head;
    
    // Wenn das erste Element null ist, wird das hinzuzufügende Wert das erste Element (head) der Liste
    if (getHead() == null) {
        setHead(new ListEL<T>(value, null));
    }
    // Ansonsten wird element solange das nächste Element der Liste, bis das nächste null ist
    else {
        while(element.next != null) {
            element = element.next;
        }
        // Hier wird dan das nächste Element des letzten Elements der Liste erstellt, mit dem hinzuzufügendem Wert
        element.next = new ListEL<T>(value, null);
    }
}

// Entfernt ein Element
public ListEL<T> remove(int index) {
    
    ListEL<T> element = head;
    
    if (index == 0) {
        setHead(head.next);
        return element;
    }
    else if (index < list.getSize() - 2) {
        element = getElement(index);
        list.getElement(index - 1).next = list.getElement(index + 1);
        return element;
    }
    else {
        element = getElement(index);
        list.getElement(index - 1).next = null;
        return element;
    }
}

// Ermittelt das Element an dem gegebenem Index
public ListEL<T> getElement(int index) {
    
    int count = 0;
    ListEL<T> element = head;
    
    while (count != index) {
        element = element.next;
        count++;
    }
    return element;
}

// Ermittelt die Groesse der dezeitigen Kette
public int getSize() {
    
    int size = 0;
    ListEL<T> element = head;
    
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        while (element.next != null) {
            element = element.next;
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }
}

public List() {
    head = null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Thread inserter = new Thread(new ListInserter(list, null));
    inserter.start();
        
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        Thread nibbler = new Thread(new ListNibbler(list, inserter));
        inserter = new Thread(new ListInserter(list, nibbler));
        
        inserter.start();
        nibbler.start();
    }
    
    Thread nibbler = new Thread(new ListNibbler(list, inserter));
    nibbler.start();
}
```

}

Comment: You need to synchronize on the object before calling `wait()` or `notify()`. But you're not even waiting and notifying on the same object.

Comment: So how would u solve it? I want the every Nibbler-instance to wait, until the next inserter notifies it

Answer (score 2):

Okay. To start with, this is bad:

```
   this.getClass().wait();
```

It indicates you haven't read the docs about wait. If you had, you would know that you need to synchronize around whatever you are calling wait, notify or notifyAll on.

```
// This is the critical code
thread.notify();
```

This is also REALLY Bad. Years ago (after I got burned) I got them to update the Javadocs to indicate that thread internally uses wait() and notify/all for thread joining. You should (almost) NEVER call wait, notify or notifyAll on Thread because of the side effects.

Here is the way to do producer/consumer with wait,notify, and notifyAll

```
List <T> sharedList = ...;

public class Producer<T> implements Runnable {
  List<T> list;
  boolean running = true;
  public Producer(List l) {
    list = l;
  }

  public void run() {
    while (running) {
      Thread.sleep(someRandomValue);
      synchronized(list) {
        //add something to the list
        list.notify();
      }
    }
  }

  public class Consumer<T> implements Runnable{
    List<T> list;
    boolean running = true;
    public Consumer(List<T> l) {
      list = l;
    }

    public void run() {
      while (running) {
        synchronized(list) {
          while (list.size() > 0) {
            //consume the value on the list
          }
          list.wait();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You may also want to look into the `volatile` keyword, as this sometimes in multithreading you want to label your variables as such.

Comment: Yes, it's my first time ever handling threads. I implemented your code, but now they dont share the same List. The size of the list at producer increments, but the size at consumer dont. I'm sorry, I just dont get into this topic :/

Comment: @John You should pass in the same list to the producer and consumer

Comment: But I do, every instance created in main got "list" as parameter.  list is a List<Integer> Object

Comment: @John And another thing I just thought of that you should look into is Thread.setDaemon. Here I think you could set the consuming thread as  Daemon thread.

Comment: @John It needs to be the same object in producer and consumer

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thread nibbler = new Thread(new Consumer(list)); they all got this List-Object, I am really good at OOP actually, but I dont get it, it seems totally different to me

Comment: @John I put the synchronized and while loops in the wrong order in one of my classes (Consumer I think - I just changed it and I've forgotten which) while should be outside of synchronized.